# Changing color of OK button in AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to change the color of the positive `button` in an `AlertDialog` in Android. Natively on my S8 the button is green, but when I try to change it, no matter what color I choose it turns up bright purple.(I've tried many different shades of blue and even pink to test)

I'm changing the color with:

```
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).textColor = R.color.color_blue
```

I am calling it after the `dialog.show()`.

Comment: I believe that dialog text color is set to due to app theme and you can't change it without changing the theme accent color in colors.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use a `theme` to control the way your dialog looks like. In your case

*R.color.color_blue* is a res id. You have to convert it to *color*. Eg

```
 dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).textColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_blue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Following way, you might get your solution

```
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(neededColor);
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(neededColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the `AlertDialog` object first, and then use it to set up to change the color of the button and then show it. (Note that on `builder` object instead of calling `show()` we call `create()` to get the `AlertDialog` object:

```
//1. create a dialog object 'dialog'
MyCustomDialog builder = new MyCustomDialog(getActivity(), "Try Again", errorMessage); 
AlertDialog dialog = builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    ...
                }

            }).create();

//2. now setup to change color of the button
dialog.setOnShowListener( new OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(COLOR_I_WANT);
    }
});

dialog.show()
```

The reason you have to do it on `onShow()` and cannot just get that button after you create your dialog is that the button would not have been created yet.

I changed `AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE` to `AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE` to reflect the change in your question. Although it is odd that "OK" button would be a negative button. Usually it is the positive button.

Answer (score 0):

You can set *Custom Theme* for *Alert Dialog* instead.

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Set *Colors* based on your choice.